# VIM: show all lines edited in session

Tags: vim

Is there a command or plugin that I can use to show all the lines I have edited in a Vim session? I would like to be able to have all the changes I have made highlighted when working in co-workers projects and lost in lines of code.

Comment: maybe you could use `vimdiff` with a backup of the original and perhaps just hide the window showing the original?  I don't know if that will work but it may be worth taking a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changesPlugin seems to work just fine for this type of thing.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3052

Once installed, just run `:EC` after making changes to a file.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using a revision control system, such as CVS, Mercurial or Subversion (etc.).  These all come with the ability to compare the working copy of a file with whatever was last checked into the repository by you or your co-workers.

Comment: I always have such a hard time forming these technical questions. I want it so as I am editing a file I can tell what I have added in that session.

Comment: @James, try the `:changes` command in Vim to see if it's doing what you want it to do.

Comment: I realized later that I could just work out of GIT diff to get what I wanted. TY for pointing out to me the obvious solution. Some times I just don`t think.

Comment: For coding that is fine, but I'm often editing config files on a remote server and they are generally not under source control (and the incremental backups don't have an easy compare function ;)